# "an etwas sich richten"-is this correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence taken from the Linguee dictionary:

> Die software **richtet sich** **an** eine bestimmte Gruppe von Benutzern.

And it gives the following translation:

> The software is aimed at a particular group of users.

Couldn't find such a reflexive use-case of "richten" on Dict.cc. It only gives "prepare oneself/get ready". Is this Linguee example even correct?

Comment: "an etwas sich richten" is not the same as "sich an etwas richten"

Comment: I don't know what search terms you used, but *sich richten an* (without quotes, order irrelevant) would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct and usual German. The basic form is 'jemand/etwas richtet sich an jemanden'

See dwds: https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=kern&q=richten%20an (though I didn't find it directly when looking up 'richten' either

Comment: It's listed in English Wiktionary; in fact several reflexive meanings are listed but #4 seems to be the one intended here. I'm not sure that a separate definition is actually necessary though since adding a reflexive pronoun seems to be a common way of making the verb passive: "Die Tür öffnet sich." You wouldn't say "The door opens itself" in English unless there are robotics involved; even then "The door opens automatically" would be better.